# Colocando metodo delete dentro de um append Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5

Galera estou com a seguinte situação, faço um append e dentro dele preciso enviar um metodo delete, para trata-lo no web service estou com duvidas, já tentei até criar um form dentro, porém não funciona, detalhe se coloco o link "http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users/'+v.iduser+'/delete" dentro do href ele funciona porém no webservice trato com metodo delete ou seja ele requisita que seja esse metodo, e se eu mudo no webservice pra get funciona, porém não e nada seguro,  Codigo jquery, :

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON('http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-list-all',function(data){
      $.each(data, function(k, v){

        $('#table-users').append("<tr>"+'<td>'+v.iduser+'</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+v.desperson+'</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+v.desemail+'</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+v.deslogin+'</td>'+
                                        '<td>'+v.inadmin+'</td>'+
                                        '<td><a href="/projetohtml/admin/users/'+v.iduser+'"class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a></td>"'+
                                        '<form action="http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users/'+v.iduser+'/delete" id="form-delete" method="delete">'+
                                        '<td><a href="#" id="iduser-delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Excluir</a></td>'+'</form>'+"</tr>");




      });

    });
 });



</script>
```

Comment: Em vez de utilizar um form, faça um Ajax que será disparado no evento de click em um algum botão de delete, passando como parâmetro o ID do item que você quer remover.

Comment: eu tentei fazer com ajax, porém parece que depois do append no id do <a href> o ajax não reconhece o elemento, não sei por que, mas fiz o mesmo codigo com ajax e não deu.

Comment: Isso acontece porque o elemento não foi carregado no DOM, mas isso é simples de resolver. Vou colocar como resposta pra te ajudar.

Comment: Beleza fico aguardando, Valeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso utilizando Ajax, que será disparado em um evento de click no botão de delete, e nele você vai pegar o ID do item que você quer remover como parâmetro.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $.getJSON('http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/users-list-all',function(data){
             $.each(data, function(k, v){
                $('#table-users').append("<tr>"+'<td>'+v.iduser+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+v.desperson+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+v.desemail+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+v.deslogin+'</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+v.inadmin+'</td>'+
                                    '<td><a href="/projetohtml/admin/users/'+v.iduser+'"class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Editar</a></td>"'+
                                    '<td><a href="javascript:;" id="'+ v.iduser +'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-user"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Excluir</a></td>'+"</tr>");
                });
          });
     });
</script>
```

Como seu elemento não foi carregado diretamente no DOM você vai precisar chamar o evento de click um pouco diferente. Note que primeiro você deve passar um elemento que foi carregado no DOM, em seguida você vai utilizar o "on" no evento de "click" no elemento que foi adicionado dinamicamente.

```
$('body').on('click', '.delete-user', function () {
    var id_user = $(this).attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { id_user: id_user },
        success: function ( response ) {
           console.log(response);
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: O garoto a requisição foi, porém to recebendo um erro mas é porque a URL ta errada , ta vindo assim : http://localhost/projetohtml/admin/href=%22/projetohtml/admin/users/43/delete%22 , eu montei ela desse jeito :  url: 'href="/projetohtml/admin/users/'+id_user+'/delete"' será o que que está errado ?

Comment: Consegui ! arrumar, cara muito obrigado deu super certo, você teria alguma doc de dom para me arrumar para dar uma estudada ? Valeu

Comment: Que bom que funcionou! Amigo eu não tenho mas você acha fácil no google.